# Force IE in Standards Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, doctype, standards-compliance, quirks-mode

I have a client that uses a proprietary CMS that is over a decade old. This CMS does not use a doctype in its html output nor can I add one. Another issue is it does not provide access to the `<head></head>` tags and therefore I cannot use meta tags to do it either.

I can however inject html, css and javascript within the `<body></body>` tags.

Unfortunately, requesting the client to change systems is not an option. I was hoping some of the brilliant minds on stack overflow might have some tips in getting IE7+ to render standards mode with the above limitations?